# Can I get the Ajax json response data in selenium robot framework

Tags: ajax, selenium, httpresponse, robotframework

Can any one tell me. Is it possible to get the ajax JSON response data to validate the particular job is DONE.

I am using the selenium robot framework for automation testing.

Comment: is their any one.. done like this???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you route your traffic through a proxy server like [Browser Mob Proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/), you should be able to accomplish this task. You could use one of the HTTP libraries to interrogate the proxy to see the traffic it captured, such as the AUT's AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(ev, jqXHR, settings) {
    jQuery("#hidden-div").html("<pre>"+jqXHR.responseText+"</pre>");
});
```

and get data with Selenium driver like this(php):

```
$driver->executeScript("return $('#hidden').html();");
```